# CSS Font Style Changes Not Working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

Could someone clarify why the below font style settings is not working in chrome, but working in IE and FireFox.

My website has the same problem, it does not pick up the CSS font settings (where `normal` is mentioned), hence I tested with [the CSS test environment from W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FH0GEHKS1HVA) and the behavior is same.

**CSS Snippet:**

- Working only in IE/FireFox: `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif normal;`
- Working in All Browsers: `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;`

Try in Chrome and IE to see difference.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
}
p.serif {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
p.sansserif {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif normal;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS font-family</h1>
<p class="serif">This is a paragraph, shown in Arial Without Normal.</p>
<p class="sansserif">This is a paragraph, shown in Arial With Normal</p>
```

**Below are the questions:**

- Could you clarify why the behavior difference between these two browsers?
- How to ensure my CSS font styles are picked by Chrome and IE/FireFox (Should I remove `normal` from all my CSS files or is there any better way to do it)?

Comment: `sans-serif normal` isn't a valid value, but `sans-serif, normal` is. Note that `normal` isn't a font-family so using it in that context doesn't make much sense. Also avoid learning from w3schools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Arguably *invalid* [`font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) declaration

If you open your browser's inspector (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> in Chrome) you will see that the CSS rule

```
p.sansserif {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif normal;
}
```

is not applied.

Per the [CSS specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/), an invalid rule is ignored, and whatever would have been applied (backwards up the cascade) is applied instead or more accurately, not overruled.
The result is `"Times New Roman"` in this case - as seen in the "Computed Styles".

[image: Chrome arguably getting it wrong]

To set the [`font-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-style) (`-variant`, `-weight`, `-stretch` or `line-height` (whichever you were trying to set to `normal`)) of text, we can either use exactly that, or use the [`font` shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font).

> The font CSS property is either a shorthand property for setting `font-style`, `font-variant`, `font-weight`, `font-size`, `line-height`, and `font-family`...

(with [caveats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font#Syntax)).

### As for the difference between IE(and FF) and Chrome

Chrome recognises in the comma delimited assertion that `sans-serif normal` is not a `font-family`, whereas IE doesn't.
If you simplify the rule to:

```
p.sansserif {
    font-family: sans-serif normal;
}
```

and view the result in IE, you'll see the `<p>` is in `"Times New Roman"` since, although IE accepts the declaration, it can't do anything sensible with it.

[image: IE arguably getting it right]

More from the specs:

> ...it is **recommended** to quote font family names that contain white space, digits, or punctuation characters other than hyphens.
>
> Font family names that happen to be the same as a keyword value (‘`inherit`’, ‘`serif`’, ‘`sans-serif`’, ‘`monospace`’, ‘`fantasy`’, and ‘`cursive`’) **must** be quoted to prevent confusion with the keywords with the same names.

So it is recommended that a font family called `sans-serif normal` be quoted as `"sans-serif normal"`.
And if a font family is using the same name as a keyword it must be quoted.

- Both Chrome and IE will accept `Comic Sans MS` or `Times New Roman` *etc.* with or without quotes, and apply them correctly.
- Chrome rejects the unquoted use of the keyword `sans-serif` where it finds it combined with `normal`, but will accept both if quoted, although it won't be able to apply that font unless it can find one with that name.
- IE accepts `sans-serif normal` as a possibly unquoted font family name, and this is arguably correct, since the keyword is only part of the presumed family name, rather than the whole thing.
- Chrome, arguably incorrectly, rejects what it presumes is a malformed assertion.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. This makes sense to me now.

Comment: Also Is there an easy way to find and consolidate all such style sheet errors in a page?

Comment: My pleasure @Achilles. I was actually quite shocked after unwinding the specs to find that IE is (arguably) behaving correctly, and Chrome is (arguably) not. There's a first time for everything I suppose! ;-) **Easy way?** The top 3 browsers all have an inspector. IE (F12) shows style rule errors with wavy red underscores, Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+i) and FF (Ctrl+Shift+C) apply a yellow warning icon and crosses them out. I know of no easier way; select each element to see the rules that are applied, and which other rules were overruled along the way.

Answer (score -2):

```
or p.font{
   font-family: font;
   align-text: center;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center. –